# Rascal MPL remove subtree in visit

Tags: rascal, subtree

How to replace a subtree with nothing in a visit?

In [Pattern With Action](https://www.rascal-mpl.org/docs/Rascal/Expressions/Visit/PatternWithAction), we see that

```
case red(l, r) => green(l, r)
```

replaces all red nodes with green nodes. I want to do something like

```
case red(l, r) => []
```

to remove all red nodes. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question. So if the abstract grammar is this:

```
data MyNode
   = green(MyNode l, MyNode r)
   | red(MyNode l, MyNode r)
   | black()
   | white()
   ;
```

Any `visit` is *not* allowed to change the type of the node it replaces. So a red node can become green, or black or white, but not "nothing". You could add a definition of nothing:

```
data MyNode = nothing();
```

And then rewrite all red nodes to `nothing`:

```
case red(_,_) => nothing()
```

So that's not really nothing :-)

However, a more common case is to remove elements from a list. In abstract syntax trees for programming languages this often happens:

```
data MyNode = nodes(list[MyNode] elements);
```

For example if the list of statements of an if-then-else statement, etc.

Now you can match on the list to remove elements:

```
case nodes([*prefix, red(_,_), *postfix)]) => nodes([*prefix, *postfix])
```

And *now* the red node is really gone.